# How to Activate MainWindow in wpf application?

Tags: wpf, window, z-order

I have a WPF application with a MainWindow and a couple of Dialogs that appear over MainWindow.
I want my main window to be activated and appear on top of all dialogs when its clicked. I have tried method Activate() but its not working ,also tried Topmost which is also not working ?
Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using `ShowDialog()` to open the other dialogs. Try using `Show()` when opening new dialogs as that won't force you to close them before being able to access the `MainWindow`. Of course without a bit more information on your code it's impossible to know exactly what causes the problem.